# reuse Microsoft Office USB stick with 7.9 GB - Error: -69877: Couldn't open device - dd: /dev/disk9: Permission denied

Tags: terminal, command-line, usb, disk-utility, disk-format

I have a USB stick from Microsoft, which was used to ship Office 2016 for Mac. I don't use Office 2016 for Mac, so wish to use this stick for other purposes.

```
/dev/disk9 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:     FDisk_partition_scheme                        *7.9 GB     disk9
   1:               Windows_NTFS Office 2016 for Mac     7.9 GB     disk9s1

> diskutil eraseDisk ExFAT DiskName /dev/disk9
Started erase on disk9
Unmounting disk
Error: -69877: Couldn't open device

> sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/disk9
Password:
dd: /dev/disk9: Permission denied

> sudo diskutil unmountDisk force /dev/disk9
Forced unmount of all volumes on disk9 was successful

> diskutil eraseDisk ExFAT DiskName /dev/disk9
Started erase on disk9
Unmounting disk
Error: -69877: Couldn't open device
```

Is this USB stick somehow readonly? How to use it?

Comment: If the stick is legal for someone else to use, trade for a blank stick.  I almost never use Office, but I wouldn't mind having it.  I'd even trade a sixteen-Gig stick for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The likely answer is that Microsoft has configured this flash drive as read-only to avoid tampering. You'll likely not be able to reuse it for anything else. This is a known practice among certain software manufacturers.

Answer (score 1):

After doing a little research on this, my conclusions are that you can try:

1. **Restarting your machine.** If you haven't restarted your machine since plugging in the USB drive then I would try that. Once you do, try reformatting the USB.
2. **Running as root.** In Terminal type in `sudo su`, press <kbd>enter</kbd> and then type in your password. Then issue the commands, being careful to type them in exactly as you need.
3. **Booting into Safe mode.** Another method is using Safe Mode, as this should allow you to encounter fewer errors than using terminal as a regular user. To boot into Safe Mode, immediately press and hold the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key down after booting up - **keep it down** until you see the login screen.

Finally, did you ever interrupt the formatting process at any time? Doing that can pose issues, so booting into Safe Mode is a good option.

**Resources:**

- https://origin-discussions-us.apple.com/thread/4806895?start=0&tstart=0
- https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/225061/242879
- https://askubuntu.com/a/771326

Comment: This Microsoft-style help I don't believe is suitable in this case. See my answer below.