# Unable to erase disk with Terminal and Disk Utility, error -69877 "Couldn't open device"

Tags: terminal, disk-utility

I am referencing this question from another user:

[Unable to format / erase hard drive](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/125965/unable-to-format-erase-hard-drive)

For some reason, this pesky Kingston drive I have does not want to erase on Disk Utility nor with the use of terminal commands. I have tried the method that [this YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eisJmWIUEAU) explains.

This is the output from running two commands on terminal:

```
~ sudo diskutil eraseDisk JHFS+ noname /dev/disk2
Started erase on disk2
Unmounting disk
Creating the partition map
Error: -69877: Couldn't open device

~ diskutil  partitionDisk  /dev/disk2  1  MBR  FAT32  MYUSB  R
Started partitioning on disk2
Unmounting disk
Creating the partition map
Error: -69877: Couldn't open device
(Is a disk in use by a storage system such as AppleRAID, CoreStorage, or APFS?)
```

Here is the information about the disk:

```
/dev/disk2 (external, physical):
  #:                       TYPE NAME           SIZE       IDENTIFIER
  0:     FDisk_partition_scheme               *15.5 GB    disk2
  1:             Windows_FAT_32 1821VPC        15.5 GB    disk2s1
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! :)  I hope you come to find this site has a lot to offer! In case you haven't already, it's worth taking the time to read the [tour](https://apple.stackexchange.com/tour). All the best!

Comment: I'm still stuck with this - did you find a solution?